# C# How to organise an array with breaks

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a spreadsheet with 12 columns and between 1 and 50 rows - I do not know how many rows there will be.

If I copy the data out of the spreadsheet I can create an array with any number of Rows and all of the data is separated into an array no problem.

I have a further 6 pieces of data from other sources within the program ‘a’ to ‘f’ - taken from various TextBoxes and DatePickers.

I need to take data from cells: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 from the array - this becomes 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 from the second row and so on (as there are 6 cells containing data I do not need in each row).

I need to order the data:

a, b, 3, 2, c, d, 1, 4, 5, 6, e, f

a, b, 15, 14, c, d, 13, 16, 17, 18, e, f

And so on.

This new string of data needs to be copied into a different spreadsheet that I cannot change.

I would like to be able to add more than 1 row at a time.

With a lot of help from stack overflow, which improved the code I was using to add 1 row at a time, I created this code:

```
string phrase = Value.Text;
string[] words = Value.Text.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r' });

List<string> values = new List<string>();

values.Add(a.Text)
values.Add(b.Text);
values.Add(words[3]);
values.Add(words[2]);
values.Add(c.Text);
values.Add(d.Text);
values.Add(words[1]);
values.Add(words[4]);
values.Add(words[5]);
values.Add(words[6]);
values.Add(e.Text);
values.Add(f.Text);
            
string outPut = String.Join("\t", values);
this.OutPutValue.Text = outPut;
```

This works for a single row.

I can add a string:

```
String newLine = “\r”
```

So I have this code:

```
values.Add(e.Text);
values.Add(f.Text);
values.Add(newLine);
values.Add(a.Text)
values.Add(b.Text);
values.Add(words[15]);
values.Add(words[14]);
values.Add(c.Text);
```

And so on...

If I try this, in the receiving spreadsheet the second Row starts on Column B instead of Column A because of the extra Tab from:

```
String.Join("\t", values);
```

Is there a way to introduce a line break so that the next line starts on Column A, rather than Column B?

Someone offered StringBuilder when I raised this before, but I failed to give enough information and I do not think that would work in this scenario (or at least I could not get my head around it).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can produce the two lines of data:

```
List<string> values = new List<string>();
StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
string[] words = Value.Text.Split(new char[] { '\t', '\r' });

values.Add(a.Text);
values.Add(b.Text);
values.Add(words[3]);
values.Add(words[2]);
values.Add(c.Text);
values.Add(d.Text);
values.Add(words[1]);
values.Add(words[4]);
values.Add(words[5]);
values.Add(words[6]);
values.Add(e.Text);
values.Add(f.Text);
sb.AppendLine(String.Join("\t", values));

values.Clear();
values.Add(a.Text);
values.Add(b.Text);
values.Add(words[15]);
values.Add(words[14]);
values.Add(c.Text);
values.Add(d.Text);
values.Add(words[13]);
values.Add(words[16]);
values.Add(words[17]);
values.Add(words[18]);
values.Add(e.Text);
values.Add(f.Text);
sb.AppendLine(String.Join("\t", values));

OutPut.AppendText(sb.ToString());
```

But does "Value.Text" above represent all of the rows, or just a single row?

Comment: Thanks Idle_Mind, couldn't implement that last night, was breaking my brain, I think I needed sleep.  Yes, Value.Text does represent all of the rows.  I still have the issue I originally had "Index out of range exception" - but I think you answered that in the last response with the IF values.Count so going to attempt to implement that today.

Comment: An index out of range exception would most likely occur whenever you are acccessing your "words" array with something like `words[15]`.  After splitting, if index 15 does not exist, then you'll get that error.  This will happen when the data is SHORTER than you expected it to be, or it is splitting the data in a way that you did not expect or foresee due to missing delimiters.

Comment: Yeah, i was hoping for a solution that is better than my brute force...which is to do a "int result = words.Count(); then "If (result < 12) messageBox "you idiot" and then Else If (result > 12 && result < 15) value.add, 12 times, then Else If (result > 15 && result < 26) value.add the first 12 items and another 12 items, and so on...til I break and and an Else "messagebox "for gods sake just stick with X" happens...still it works, which is something.